# Lacp over two linux boxes - something like MC-LAG

Tags: linux, lacp, openvswitch, lag

I have two linux box'es which are gateways for some kind of virtualized network (Openvswitch, GRE).
I am trying to optimize performance - so I decided, that I have to try remove routing part from them (they will be only forwarding packets to virtualized network, but stacked L3 switches will make routing)

I need to find a way to tell a switch, that those linux boxes are one machine in LACP - why no static lag? Because port will be active even when server wont be up, so it will make connection problems (for example, when server is booting - port for switch look's UP but soft is not working)

So i need some kind of MC-LAG on linux - not even this - i need to tell switch "lag is here" using lacp.

I was trying to set bonding on two hosts with same mac and IP address, but switch see only one host, and when i make ifdown on one server, it see second one.

I was trying to capture lacp packet on one host using tcpdump, and send it every sec on second server, but its not working too :(

Do you have any idea?

I found something like this:
https://docs.cumulusnetworks.com/display/CL25/Multi-Chassis+Link+Aggregation+-+CLAG+-+MLAG
https://docs.cumulusnetworks.com/display/CL25/Virtual+Router+Redundancy+-+VRR

But cumulus is expensive solution...

ps. Sorry for bad english...